# multiple page transitions in a windows phone application depending on target page

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-phone

How can I implement multiple page transitions in a windows phone application depending on which page I'm navigating to/from?

For example I have the main page, a settings page and a details page.
I want the transition to be swivel when I'm going to/from the settings page and to be turnstile when i'm going from/to details page.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

This [GeekChamp](http://www.geekchamp.com/) article covers all various ways you use the [Windows Phone Toolkit](http://phone.codeplex.com/) to animate page transitions and other elements...

http://www.geekchamp.com/articles/windows-phone-7-navigation-transitions-step-by-step-guide

Towards the end of the article are examples of how to dynamically set an animation based on, say, a button click...

**1. Define the animation**

```
private void StartTransition()
{
    RotateTransition rotatetransition = new RotateTransition();
    rotatetransition.Mode = RotateTransitionMode.In90Clockwise;

    PhoneApplicationPage phoneApplicationPage =
    (PhoneApplicationPage)(((PhoneApplicationFrame)Application.Current.RootVisual)).Content;

    ITransition transition = rotatetransition.GetTransition(phoneApplicationPage);
    transition.Completed += delegate
    { 
        transition.Stop(); 
    };
    transition.Begin();
}
```

**2. Call animation on button click**

```
private void btnRotate_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Page2.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
    StartTransition();
}
```

**or when navigating based on page name**

```
protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnNavigatedFrom(e);

    if (e.Uri.ToString().Contains("SlidePage"))
    {
        slideAnimation();
    }

    if (e.Uri.ToString().Contains("TurnstilePage"))
    {
        turnstileAnimation();
    }
}
```

Comment: There's one issue... I want to change the transition based on the uri i navigate to, not the button I click.
Using this technique would mean that i have to call StartTransition on every button click. This doesn't sound right but i will have to use it if there's no better solution.

Another technique in the article is changing the transition in OnNavigatedTo and OnNavigatedFrom.
I've tried this and it didn't work, these methods were called after the transition was initialized.

Comment: You can set the animation in `OnNavigatedFrom`, look in the `NavigationEventArgs`... `e.Uri.ToString().Contains("PageName")`